# Token in spring's request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm recieving sensitive data from http request, which is mapped to object.

```
public class XXXX {

    private Long id;
    private String token;
}
```

Ive read that we shouldnt store passwords etc in string due to Immutablity etc. So I could do char[] instead, but does it make sense when there is whole spring container over it, jackson with his maps deserializing it to object etc?

Comment: "there is whole spring container" means? Your question is not clear.

Comment: for example theres request object contains this information, there are jackson maps containing key/values with this information

Comment: *jackson with his maps deserializing it to object etc* -- your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: tbh I dont know how to be more clear about it, since jackson here is not the point, and its been brought up by me as example